# save json data containing polygon coordinates data into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring

i have json data for a neighborhood that am trying to save all the data in mysql database but am failing to save the
boundaries coordinates data for a neighborhood.
any help will be appreciated

this is how the json data looks like

```
{
    "id": 21,
    "name": "CARNEGIE HILL",
    "boundaries": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -73.9493302,
                    40.7851967
                ],
                [
                    -73.9538181,
                    40.7870864
                ],
                [
                    -73.9541536,
                    40.7872279
                ],
                [
                    -73.9557237,
                    40.7878894
                ],
                [
                    -73.9604089,
                    40.7815447
                ],
                [
                    -73.9539823,
                    40.7788333
                ],
                [
                    -73.9493302,
                    40.7851967
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "area": 500024.233856916
}
```

And these are the java classes am using

```
public class Neighborhood {

@Id
private Long id;

private String name;

@Embedded
private Boundaries boundaries;

private String area;

public Neighborhood() {
}
```

}

```
public class Boundaries {
private String type;

private String coordinates;

public Boundaries() {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can save JSON data directly in MySQL by using the JSON column type.

Here is a reference to how that works and how to use it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html